# Spring integration and session variables

Tags: spring, spring-integration, email

Good morning everybody,

I have a spring integration mail module that I am using to listen to incoming emails.

I wanted to move this module into a web app, so that I can cleanly start and stop the adapters from the web app.

The issue I am now facing, is that my program handling emails needs a session scope variable.
(In the non web version of this program it used a singleton. I now need this data to stored in the session, because of the web based nature of the application (value will depend on the user)).

And when I am accessing this session variable from the email handling program I have an exception telling that Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread.

I understand that Spring integration may have created its own thread, and that this thread cannot access the web session.

I have this configuration for the object accessed from the session:

```
<bean id="localManager" class="com.xxx.ManagerImpl" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</bean>
```

The bean handling the emails, and needing the localManager bean:

```
<int:service-activator id="serviceActivator" input-channel="receiveChannel" ref="mailService" method="handleMail"/>
```

Within the method handleMail, I am accessing the localManager:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="localManager")
private Manager manager;
```

This is when calling a method on the manager that I have the exception Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread.

Is it possible to make the two work together and have the email management thread access a session scoped variable?

PS: I have other beans in my web app (a JSF app) accessing the localManager without any issue. This is really specific to the integration thread

Thanks

Gilles

Comment: That will never work. How can it have access to the session, it is a background polling proces that knows nothing about the application it runs it, let alone that it runs in a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to package the 2 together may not be the simplest thing to do...

But if you want to control your Spring integration module from a webapp, why don't you add an inbound adapter (probably an http-inbound) in your spring integration module ? Then all you need to do in your webapp is perform an http call to that end point, passing user specific parameters to your spring integration module as part of the HTTP request.

On reception of the incoming HTTP request, your spring module can parse the message and send a message on control bus to start/stop the intended components.

I have done something very similar with an RMI inbound gateway :

```
<int-rmi:inbound-gateway request-channel="rmiIncomingRequestChannel" />

<int:channel id="rmiIncomingRequestChannel" />

<int:service-activator method="myModuleInterfaceAction"
    input-channel="rmiIncomingRequestChannel" ref="rmiToControlMessage" />

<bean id="rmiToControlMessage"
    class="myModule.rmi.controller.impl.RmiInterfaceControllerImpl">
    <property name="controlChannel" ref="controlChannel" />
</bean>

<int:channel id="controlChannel" />

<int:control-bus input-channel="controlChannel" />
```

According to documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html) it looks like you'll have to deploy your Spring Integration module in Tomcat to be able to have an http listener. Or that's probably something Spring Boot can solve for you, with an embedded tomcat in your jar.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very good. In a way close to what I had first, where the web app only sent start/stop messages to the module, but did not think about sending parameters ... My question then is: i can send parameters to the end point, but how can I pass this paramater to my mailService (ref=mailService) bean? Thanks

Comment: In the snippet I provided, just like I have injected the controlChannel in rmiToControlMessage, you can wire your mailService and act on it based on the messages you receive

Comment: This is what I have done. This works well. Thanks you very much.

Comment: This leads to another question: I now have my mailService running on another web app, hosting all my services (call it Remote), and it is accessed remotely from the monitoring web app to stop and start the. My question is: when I am stopping  the Remote web app, are all the Spring Integration properly stopped, or should I call stop before?